# UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey height incorrect (should be 48pt less)

Tags: ios, iphone, uikeyboard

I am trying to scroll my view according to keyboard height. Here is my code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        lastKeyboardFrame = [note.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    }];
```

(after I obtain the `lastKeyboardFrame` I use it to push my views top etc.)

I have some text views and my view controller is their delegate. Here is how I animate the whole view up:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    self.editingViewBottomConstraint.constant = lastKeyboardFrame.size.height;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    self.editingViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
    lastKeyboardFrame = CGRectZero;
}
```

`self.editingViewBottomConstraint` is the bottom constraint of my view to bottom layout guide. It works, but the keyboard height is incorrectly displayed. Here is how it displays:

[image]

After some trial and error, I've found out that 'extra' space is exactly 48pt in height. If I subtract 48 from the height, it works well:

[image]

Tested both in iOS 7 iPhone 4s simulator and iPhone 6 Plus, it's the same regardless of screen size. The first thing I've considered was predictive input bar at the top, but then I've realized that the problem is also persistent on iOS 7.1 too, and that my keyboard (Turkish) doesn't even have that bar available.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: @rob5408 nope, unfortunately not. I've ended up using my view as inputAccessoryView on my textView instead of begging for apparently buggy/messy keyboard notifications from the system.

Comment: in my case my view is already the inputAccessoryView. I use this approach all throughout this app and this is the only place it goes haywire. I'll do some research. Thanks!

Comment: I kinda forgot that my UITableView didn't extend all the way to the bottom of the superview, I have a button at the bottom. So the keyboard dutifully reports it's height and I adjust the insets, but I needed to adjust the insets to the keyboard height less the height of my button.

Comment: Hey @CanPoyrazoğlu did you find issue for the problem??

Comment: @benhi unfortunately, not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer.

I'm pretty sure you have a tab bar. The tab bar height is 49 points.

When your constant value is 0 (keyboard hidden), your view is still 49 points above 0.

So you have 2 options:
1. Keep subtracting 49 points.
2. Present the view controller instead of pushing to get rid of the tab bar.

Comment: this is correct. I ended up doing `[[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height-self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height`

Comment: I am presenting the view controller and still having the same issue

Answer (score 10):

For anyone still stumbling on this: I think the safest answer is buried in the comments of @Oded's answer:

You should get the height of the `UITabBar` then subtract it from the keyboard height:

**Objective-C:**:

```
[[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height-self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.‌​size.height
```

**Swift**:

```
let tabBarHeight = tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0
let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue ?? 0.0
let adjustedKeyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.height - tabBarHeight
```

Comment: It helps for iPhone 10 issue.

Comment: We should not be struggling with this all these years later. iOS developers are responsible for moving the content when the keyboard deploys, yet it it nearly impossible to get the actual size of the keyboard.

Comment: `keyboardFrame.height` otherwise you cannot subtract `CGFloat` from `CGRect`